# How to convert map<int, string> from c++11 to c++98?

Tags: c++, c++98

I have this code in C++11:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

map<int, string> finalStates =
{
    { 0, "eroare lexicala" },
    { 1,  "identificator" } 
};
```

And I tried to convert it to C++98 like:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::map<int, std::string> finalStates;

finalStates.insert( std::pair<int, std:string> (0, "eroare lexicala"));
finalStates.insert( std::pair<int, std:string> (1,  "identificator"));
```

which gives me the error 'finalStates' does not name a type|

Please, help.

Comment: The code to insert something into the map must be inside a function. It can't be at a declaration level. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: `gives me the error 'finalStates' does not name a type` Please post the exact error message. Did you try to call a function `finalStates.insert(` at file scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error 'finalStates' does not name a type

In C++, you cannot have statements in the outer (global) scope. You must put them in some function. The C++11 code has no statement, only a definition.

C++98 alternative (especially useful if the map should be `const`):

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::map<int, std::string> construct_final_states()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> finalStates;
    finalStates.insert( std::pair<int, std::string> (0, "eroare lexicala"));
    finalStates.insert( std::pair<int, std::string> (1,  "identificator"));
    return finalStates;
}

std::map<int, std::string> finalStates = construct_final_states();
```

Comment: I had a hard time not typing `auto`!

Comment: This is also my preferred way of initializing such maps. One might also consider to making this function static and putting it into an anonymous namespace, so it will be only called inside the current module.

Comment: You could simply insert default-constructed string with `operator[]` and assign to it instead of typing out the pair type: `finalStates[0]="eroare lexicala"; finalStates[1]="identificator";`. It's cheap enough (and cheaper than creating a temporary `std::string` and copying it, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Outside any function you may use only declarations.

You can for example declare an auxiliary array like

```
const std::pair<int, std::string> a[] = 
{
    std::pair<int, std::string>( 0, "eroare lexicala" ),
    std::pair<int, std::string>( 1, "identificator" )
};
```

and then declare the map

```
std::map<int, std::string> finalStates( a, a + sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have covered it right. The only I thing I'd like to add, if you want your map initialized **at the time of global object construction**, you might want to place the initialization code into a global object constructor:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::map<int, std::string> finalStates;

class finalStates_init
{
public:
    finalStates_init()
    {
        finalStates.insert( std::pair<int, std:string> (0, "eroare lexicala"));
        finalStates.insert( std::pair<int, std:string> (1,  "identificator"));
    }
} the_finalStates_init;
```

This way, the map will have its values by the time `main()` starts. Either that, or *derive* a class from `map<int, string>` and provide a constructor.